# When buying a separate Pokéwalker, does it have to be from your country?

Tags: region-lock, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

I know Pokéwalkers are wayyy out of style and *SO* 2009, but I lost mine pretty early on after I got Heart Gold and I still miss having it around, so I was thinking of buying one on eBay, but I really doubt there'll be any Pokéwalkers on eBay from Swedish sellers.

Would it be possible to buy a foreign Pokewalker and connect it to a Swedish localization of HG/SS?

I remember buying an American copy of SSBB when it just came out, but it didn't work on our Swedish Wii, so I'm worried the same problem would arise with this...

Answer (score 1):

HH/SS were released before region locking was added to DS games so the pokéwalker should work from any country, just make sure you get it in your language

Also it is possible to un region lock your wii so you can play SSBB

Comment: Just note that 'un-regionlocking' your Wii is not endorsed by Nintendo and will void your warranty.

Comment: @OMGBACONROFL I doubt anyone still has warranty on their wii anymore :)